# Regular expression Java Merge Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I've these three regular expressions. They work individually but i would like to merge them in a single pattern.

```
regex1 = [0-9]{16}
regex2 = [0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{4}
regex3 = [0-9]{4}[ ][0-9]{4}[ ][0-9]{4}[ ][0-9]{4}
```

I use this method:

```
Pattern.compile(regex);
```

Which is the regex string to merge them?

Comment: Merge in what way? Are they alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [backreferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html#backref):

```
[0-9]{4}([ -]|)([0-9]{4}\1){2}[0-9]{4}
```

This will only match if the seperators are either all

- spaces
- hyphens
- blank

`\1` means "this matches exactly what the first [capturing group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) – expression in parentheses – matched".

Since `([ -]|)` is that group, both other separators need to be the same for the pattern to match.

You can [simplify it further](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html) to:

```
\d{4}([ -]|)(\d{4}\1){2}\d{4}
```

Comment: +1 Nice, didn't realise back-references worked within the pattern like that.

Answer (score 1):

The following should match anything the three patterns match:

```
regex = [0-9]{4}[- ]?[0-9]{4}[- ]?[0-9]{4}[- ]?[0-9]{4}
```

That is, I'm assuming you are happy with either a hyphen, a space **or** nothing between the numbers?

*Note: this will also match situations where you have any combination of the three, e.g.*

```
0000-0000 00000000
```

*which may not be desired?*

---

Alternatively, if you need to match any of the three individual patterns then just concatenate them with `|`, as follows:

```
([0-9]{16})|([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{4} [0-9]{4} [0-9]{4} [0-9]{4})
```

(Your original example appears to have unnecessary square brackets around the space and hyphen)

Comment: Yes, it partially work. But i need that the string contains all "-" or " ". Is this regex valid? 
[0-9]{4}[-]?[0-9]{4}[-]?[0-9]{4}[-]?[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4}[ ]?[0-9]{4}[ ]?[0-9]{4}[ ]?[0-9]{4}